# Rotating an SVG element using css :hover only leads to element flickering

Tags: css, svg, rotation, rotatetransform

For the **full code** have a look at https://codepen.io/fcc-danielw/pen/oNBLjrj

The relevant partials are shown below:

```html
<svg width="235" height="381" viewBox="0 0 235 381" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...
<g id="images">
          <g id="img1">
            <rect id="Rectangle 10" x="37" y="158" width="71" height="71" rx="3" fill="#C4C4C4" fill-opacity="0.25" />
            <mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="38" y="159" width="70" height="70">
              <rect id="Rectangle 9" x="38" y="159" width="70" height="70" rx="3" fill="#C4C4C4" />
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#mask0)">
              <g id="mountains">
                <path id="Polygon 1" d="M58.5 187L89.2439 229.75H27.7561L58.5 187Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
                <path id="Polygon 2" d="M94.5 187L125.244 229.75H63.7561L94.5 187Z" fill="#C4C4C4" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
...
</g>
...
</svg>
```

```css
#img1 {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    #img1:hover {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform-origin: 35px 35px;
    }
```

For some reason, when hovering over `#img1`, rather than rotating as expected, it simply starts flickering. What is the issue here? What am I doing wrong?

[image: vdvsvs]

Answer (score 0):

The element not flickering , hover effect just repeated several times.
You can stop this by using transition.

You're #img element CSS should be like this

```
#img1 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 9s;
}
```

Comment: Definitely gets rid of the flickering (even if I don't completely comprehend why). I was hoping it would turn in place but it behaves super odd: https://s4.gifyu.com/images/ani_2f4fb2cfe164354a0.gif

Comment: i think u can use animation , it will do what u wand :)

Comment: that is because you have transformed the origin

Comment: Not transforming the origin leads to things becoming even worse 